# How to solve com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.NotFoundException in IBM Watson?

Tags: java, api, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, language-translation

I am trying to incorporate IBM Watson translation library in my application.

Below is the sample code that i am trying

```
LanguageTranslator service = new LanguageTranslator();
        service.setUsernameAndPassword("user","password");

        TranslateOptions translateOptions = new TranslateOptions.Builder()
          .addText("नमस्ते")
          .source(Language.HINDI)
          .target(Language.ENGLISH)
          .build();

        TranslationResult result = service.translate(translateOptions)
          .execute();

        System.out.println(result);
```

When i use source language as `Language.HINDI` and target as `Language.ENGLISH`, i am getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.NotFoundException: Model not found.
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.processServiceCall(WatsonService.java:415)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$1.execute(WatsonService.java:174)
    at com.terrierdemo.LanguageTranslatorIBM.main(LanguageTranslatorIBM.java:23)
```

But for some language combinations`(Language.ENGLISH|Language.SPANISH`) I am getting expected result. Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error description, it is clear that the translator model is not available for your source and target languages. You Check for the available source models using this [List Models](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/language-translator/api/v2/?java#list-models). I did not see any default model that can translate Hindi to English. You need to create a model for this. [Create Model](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/language-translator/api/v2/?java#create-model)